# How to run a specific command when makefile has a error?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, makefile

I have a makefile that calls

```
...
```

> @lessc less/mything.less > style.uncompressed.css

can i run a command like "beep" or "paplay ..." when the lessc compiler has errors? If how do i do it?

I am running this in background and have a script checking folder for changes, if something changes this makefile is executed. I don't have a 2nd monitor and i don't want the console to be always on top. So a sound when a error  would be great. Maybe someone knows another solution for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make's default action on build failure is to exit with a non-zero exit code. If make terminates with a non-zero exit code, you can make a simple wrapper around it that invokes the sound generation command:

```
make
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    tput bel
    aplay <sound to play>.mp3
fi
```

Comment: `echo -e "^G"` actually prints me "^G" in the terminal cant say if this makes a beep bc i have no pc speaker on my desktop pc. But i use "paplay" (pulseaudioplay i think) under ubuntu and its working great. this is so cool. wanted this for ages. thanks.

Comment: you can also use `tput bel` instead of the echo line (should have used this in the answer) - this causes the beep. Most linuxes interpret the beep and use fancier audio

Comment: Note that `[` is actually a command as opposed to this being a special shell syntax.  `[` simply evaluates the expression and provides a return value.  This form looks good and all, but note that `if make; then` would work as well, I believe.

Comment: @altendky It also works, I tend to use the explicit form from habit

Comment: @Petesh The explicit form is probably better in general.  I was just making certain it was understood what it was.

Comment: you can call make using something like `make "$@"` to pass arguments to make.